# Different ways to say you are leaving work for the day

Tags: synonyms

What are some formal ways to tell the boss or colleagues in the office you are leaving for the day? I am new to this, I googled and found [this](http://www.phrasemix.com/collections/15-ways-to-say-goodbye-in-english) link but I want some more professional or creative way to say this other than,

1. I am leaving now
2. I will make a move now
3. I am leaving for the day

Comment: "I'm outta here!!" is what I've mostly heard (and said).  (But you should probably use "I'm leaving for the day."  And "I will make a move now" is simply confusing.)

Comment: @Hot Licks, May I know why are you saying "I will make a move now" as confusing? Because in my office some people say this before leaving for the day.

Comment: I agree with Hot Licks. I've never heard of "I will make a move" in the US.

Comment: "I will make a move now" does not imply where you are moving to.  You could be just moving to the next cube, or you could be moving to a different country.  If it's common in your office that's a relatively local thing.  (I'm guessing it might be a literal translation of an idiom in your national language.)

Comment: *Make a move now* is a very informal way of saying "I'm going to leave", but in my experience as a speaker of American English, it is said by a visitor, or by someone at a party, and it means "get ready to leave". "leave for the day" on the other hand would be commonly used at a place of employment.  "Make a move" here is in the same register as "get going" or "hit the road".

Comment: @TimRomano - Actually, at a party "I will make a move" would tend to imply you're about to "hit" on someone who has caught your eye.

Comment: @HotLicks: Context is all. "We've got to be making a move",  said often to the hosts of a gathering, or to other "company" at the gathering, means "We have to be going." I've heard the expression hundreds of times, as it's in the idiolect of my mother's extended family.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm **[clocking off](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clock+off)**

> clock off or clock out
>  vb
>   1. (intr, adverb) to depart from work, esp when it involves registering the time of departure on a card

(thefreedictionary.com)

Comment: "Clocking out" is far more idiomatic.  And it really only applies to jobs where you must record your time on the job.

Comment: @HotLicks is this regional variation? I've almost always heard clocking *off*, clicking *out* seems less idiomatic to me.

Comment: I said "*clocking* out".

Comment: @HotLicks It is idiomatic. It especially applies then but not only. It came from that meaning but now means simply leaving work, ending a shift, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Formal ways:

- I'm done for the day. See you tomorrow (or on Monday, for e.g)!
- Let me call it a day! Good evening (or night, depending on time)!|
- I'm leaving! Enjoy the rest of the day (if time is left of the workday)
- May I leave? (asking permission, if allowed to leave early). (Good)bye!
- I'm all done; heading home. Bye!

You can be creative, but you don't want to sound 'outlandish', for sure!

Comment: You would not say "Let me go now!"  That implies that you're being held against your will.

Comment: @Hot Licks: Literally, yes. I often say that, while picking up my bag and about to leave. But you're right.

Comment: "I'm pushing off" is very informal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making like a bread truck... and hauling buns.  Which becomes "bread-truck".  Used as in "time to breadtruck".  It may be used exclusively in my shop.